# How to use MKMapView's "Shows User Location" in iOS8?

Tags: ios, ios8, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

When you add an `MKMapView` component to the view in Interface Builder, there are checkboxes that let you configure what it shows:

[image]

When you check "User Location", it automatically shows user's location on the map.

However, since iOS 8 you're supposed to ask for location permission before showing user's location. If you don't, you get a "Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting" warning in the console.

So I've added a `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key to the plist, and added this code to `viewDidLoad`:

```
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
    CLLocationManager().requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

This doesn't seem to work though. I do get a popup asking for permission, but before I select an answer, it hides by itself, the map loads below it and I get the warning in the console.

I know I can set the `showsUserLocation` property in the code instead, only after getting the permission; but my point is, there is this checkbox in IB that is supposed to do the same thing, except it starts the tracking immediately. Does that mean that we're not supposed to use this checkbox at all since iOS 8? Or am I using it incorrectly?

--

Update: actually, the popup hides by itself regardless if "shows user location" is set or not. I've tried doing it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` instead, but that didn't help. So I'm not sure where exactly am I supposed to call `requestwhenInUseAuthorization` when using an `MKMapView`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `CLLocationManager` instance is released by ARC after the method completed executing. As soon as the instance was released, the dialog disappeared. The solution was rather simple. Change the CLLocationManager instance from being a method-level variable to be a class-level instance variable, and make it **Strong** - this is for ObjC :)

For Swift... do something like that:

```
    class YourViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    ...
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Ask for permission for location
            locationManager.delegate = self

            if(locationManager.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")) {
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                //or
                //locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
    ...
    }
```

so... don't use `CLLocationManager().requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` - instead use `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` - locationManager declared early

Comment: Ah, you're right, ARC makes me forget about memory management completely and that sometimes leads to things like this. Looks like now it doesn't even show the pop up at all if I don't retain the manager. If I do, it works as it should, thanks.

Comment: Nice I guess the reference to the delegate isn't enough to keep the instance around. Thanks again!

Comment: @Quincy Delegates should always be WEAK, otherwise you'll get retain cycles everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`requestWhenInUseAuthorization` is asynchronous — make sure you are listening to authorization change status in your map view delegate before actually trying to track or show the user's location.

Comment: But here's the thing, I'm not starting to track the user's location in code. If I check "Shows: User Location" in IB, then the NIB loader does it, and it starts it automatically and asynchronously with whatever I am doing in the delegate/controller. So what I'm asking is, is there any way to do it properly using this checkbox in iOS 8?